# How to show pound sign in customer display pole?

Tags: c#

I am using C# windows forms and I have a customer display pole with COM port and I can display any text I want and it is working with no issues. However when I send `£` sign to the display using the following code the screen displays the `?` instead of `£` sign.

```
serialPort1.Write("£");
```

I had a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627694/how-to-insert-a-symbol-pound-euro-copyright-into-a-textbox) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373925/encoding-issue-of-euro-sign) but no luck.

Anyone knows how can I display the `£` sign on customer display pole?
Thank you

Comment: Do you know which encoding the display is expecting, i.e. a specific code page, ascii or some generic encoding? Especially for ascii characters higher than 128 there could either be unimplemented characters or otherwise mapped ones.

Comment: Characters out of classic ASCII range may, or may not be realised on different devices. Characters abobe 127 sometimes are described as 'codepage'

Comment: I really do not know how to check which encoding the display uses.

Comment: this is the user manual:  http://www.bixolon.com/upload/download/manual_bcd-1100_user_english_rev_1_02.pdf

Comment: http://www.bixolon.com/upload/download/bcd_code_pages_manual_english_rev_2_00.pdf

Comment: On page 12 of that manual it describes how to select character code tables and international character set. What is currently set and would it help to adjust those settings? Default is U.S.A., maybe there is a U.K. setting?

Comment: No UK settings, I sent $ sign and yes it works but not the £ sign. any idea?

Comment: It does say in the second manual on the last page. The code is 3 for UK. You then need to change the memory switch Msw11 as detailed on p12 of the first manual to 3 I guess, but don't ask me how you do that.